# Cloning md partitions for recovery

Tags: software-raid, dd, mdadm

I have a failed software RAID5 (3x500GB disks) that I'm trying to recover. I don't want to try some of the more risky steps on the actual disks, so I want to clone them to new partitions on a new 3TB disk. I created 3 500GB partitions with gparted, then used:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/dev/sdb1
dd if=/dev/sdd1 of=/dev/sdb2
dd if=/dev/sde1 of=/dev/sdb3
```

to clone each md partition into them. But mdadm can't see a superblock on the new cloned paritions. How should I clone them such that I can use them in mdadm to try to recover my data?

If I try to activate the array, I currently get the following in /proc/mdstat:

```
Personalities :
md0 : inactive sdc1[0](S) sde1[2](S) sdd1[1](S)
      1465151808 blocks

unused devices: <none>
```

More info, from fdisk (as I created them using gparted, I made the target partitions are slightly larger to be safe):

```
Disk /dev/sdc1: 500.1 GB, 500105217024 bytes
Disk /dev/sdd1: 500.1 GB, 500105217024 bytes
Disk /dev/sde1: 500.1 GB, 500105217024 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb1: 500.2 GB, 500170752000 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb2: 500.2 GB, 500170752000 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb3: 500.2 GB, 500170752000 bytes
```

And finally, mdadm --examine for each partition:

```
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb{1,2,3}
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb1.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb2.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb3.
$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sd{c,d,e}1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : f8d0c619:9f54ad08:bd0b98c0:101144a1
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 18 01:56:33 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 488383936 (465.76 GiB 500.11 GB)
     Array Size : 976767872 (931.52 GiB 1000.21 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sat Sep 27 13:59:35 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 2
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : cbf4174b - correct
         Events : 5983

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1

   0     0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   1     1       0        0        1      faulty removed
   2     2       0        0        2      faulty removed
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : f8d0c619:9f54ad08:bd0b98c0:101144a1
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 18 01:56:33 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 488383936 (465.76 GiB 500.11 GB)
     Array Size : 976767872 (931.52 GiB 1000.21 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sat Sep 27 08:00:42 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : cbf3c2d6 - correct
         Events : 5940

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1

   0     0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   1     1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : f8d0c619:9f54ad08:bd0b98c0:101144a1
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 18 01:56:33 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 488383936 (465.76 GiB 500.11 GB)
     Array Size : 976767872 (931.52 GiB 1000.21 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sat Sep 27 08:00:42 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : cbf3c2e8 - correct
         Events : 5940

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1

   0     0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   1     1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
```

Comment: Please show the contents of /dev/mdstat

Comment: I've added it, but I don't see how this information leads me to the correct dd options for cloning the partitions in a usable way...

Comment: Are you sure the new partitions are as big as the old ones? If dd didn't emit errors, then you're probably safe. I don't think using dd differently will help. Rather, I suspect mdadm will need to be convinced to look for superblocks. Can you add the output of mdadm --examine on each partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you're using 0.90 metadata. That is stored at a given offset from the *end* of the device, so if you've copied data to a larger device, then mdadm can't find the metadata (as it's not at the end where it's expected).

I recommend you resize the new partitions to be exactly the same size as the originals, and the metadata should be found (no need to recopy the data, as long as you don't move the beginning of the partition).

Additional note: adding an option bs=1024k to dd makes it all go a lot faster.